# How to execute Powershell script on the fly

Tags: powershell

If I have a Powershell script accessible through HTTP, how can I download it and execute it on the fly like what we can do in the bash?

```
curl --user user:pass https://fake.url | bash
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## First of all, you shouldn't do that. I mean, downloading random code from the web and running it without taking a look at it? Yikes!

## Yes, it's convenient, but it's also a horribly stupid idea, just as `curl | bash`, or even worse, `curl | sudo bash` is.

<sub>In most cases you can probably use `WebClient.DownloadString` and pass it to `Invoke-Expression`: `Invoke-Expression (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString(«url»)`. I'm not sure whether that still opens a `script:` scope for variables, though, so if that scope is used in the script it might not work. In that case you can download it as a file and execute the script. Then you also have to take care of the execution policy, though.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for reminding me download and executing random script is a dumb idea. What I am actually going to do is download script from an internal central repository which script is verified already.

And I successfully run following command:

`Invoke-RestMethod    -Uri https://fake.url    -Method Get |Invoke-Expression`

Comment: It seems to be a popular way to install PowerShell modules these days. WMF5 apparently brings an `Install-Module` that can download modules from a central repository (the PowerShell Gallery) which means that once everyone is on PowerShell 5 (might just take a while) we can let those things die for most cases.

Comment: If this isnt being run interactively make sure to check for errors etc. I would dump the script block to stdout to help with troubleshooting down the line #murphyslaw

Answer (score 1):

Try

`curl --user user:pass https://fake.url | powershell -Command -`

If the value of Command is "-", the command text is read from standard input.